# How can I conditionally format the label for a field in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-admin

I have this code-part in my Edit view:

```
         <FormTab label="Jellemzok">
             <SelectInput label="Tipus" source="type" choices={[
                 {id: 0, name: "type1"},
                 {id: 1, name: "type2"},
                 {id: 2, name: "type3"},
                 {id: 3, name: "type4"},
                 {id: 4, name: "type5"},
                 {id: 5, name: "type6"},
                 {id: 6, name: "type7"},
                 {id: 7, name: "type8"},
             ]} optionText="name" />
             <TextInput source="data_1" />
             <TextInput source="data_2" />
             <TextInput source="data_3" />
             <TextInput source="data_4" />
             <TextInput source="data_5" />
             <TextInput source="data_6" />
         </FormTab>
```

I have to label the data fields based on the Type I select above.

So:

if I choose "type1", my label should be:

```
             <TextInput label="label1" source="data_1" />
             <TextInput label="label2" source="data_2" />
             <TextInput label="label3" source="data_3" />
             <TextInput label="label4" source="data_4" />
             <TextInput label="label5" source="data_5" />
             <TextInput label="label6" source="data_6" />
```

but if I chose "type6", my label should be like this:

```
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label1" source="data_1" />
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label2" source="data_2" />
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label3" source="data_3" />
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label4" source="data_4" />
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label5" source="data_5" />
             <TextInput label="this_is_another_label6" source="data_6" />
```

how can I simply do it?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the FormDataConsumer component:

`<FormDataConsumer>
  {({ formData }) => {
    const label = formData.type === 0 ? "label" : "this_is_another_label"
    return (
      <>
        <TextInput label={label + 1} source="data_1" />
        <TextInput label={label + 2} source="data_2" />
        <TextInput label={label + 3} source="data_3" />
        <TextInput label={label + 4} source="data_4" />
        <TextInput label={label + 5} source="data_5" />
        <TextInput label={label + 6} source="data_6" />
      </>
    )
  }}
</FormDataConsumer>`

Comment: Thanks Max! It was working. If I want to make that visible only if formData.type is defined, where should I put the selector? to the return? or before the const?

Comment: Better before const, just check for undefined explicitly: if (formData.type !== undefined) {...}